# AWS boto3 invoke lambda returns None payload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm not quite sure why this piece of code fails, please I'd be happy to hear your thoughts. I've used examples from boto3 and its works in general, but I'd get an AttributeError all of a sudden in some cases. Please explain what I am doing wrong because if a payload is None, I will get a JSON decoding error but not a None object.

Here is a simplified version of a code that causes the exception.

```py
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='...')
res = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='func',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=json.dumps({'param': 123})
)
payload = json.loads(res["Payload"].read().decode('utf-8'))
for k in payload.keys():
    print(f'{k} = {payload[k]}')
```

The error

```
----
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
```

Comment: Are you returning anything at the end of your lambda?  What returns when you run it locally?  Can you verify your lambda is running?

Comment: @CoinGraham should return something, but wouldn’t it be a JSON decoding error if the StreamingBody is empty? Just trying to understand how does it work.

Comment: Not sure.  What is it actually returning before you json.load it?

Comment: @CoinGraham honestly, I don't know I've got this only once so far and couldn’t reproduce. For some reason payload is None and json.loads do not raise any errors. It's thrown me off and I have no expectations. Any ideas why that’s happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replicated your issue in my environment by creating a lambda that doesn't return anything and calling it using boto3.  The "null" object passes through the json loads without error but doesn't have any keys since it's not a dictionary.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    pass
```

I created my code just like yours and got the same error.  Weirdly, I was able to get the json error by attempting to print out the streaming body with this line

```
print(res["Payload"].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

before loading it.  I have no idea why this happens.

Edit:  Looks like once you read from the StreamingBody object it's empty from then on.  https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody.  My recommendation is to read the data from the streaming body and check for "null" and process as normal.

Comment: Let me get it straight. You've got an attitude error as well, but after an attempt to print it out, you've got a decoding error. Is it right? Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Yes.  I get the exact attribute error if I use your code against a lambda that doesn't return anything.  So I think this is the answer.  Fix the lambda return and you'll stop getting attribute errors.

I think that once you read from the streaming body it changes it in some way.  That's my best guess on why it fails in one case instead of the other.  Regardless, you can add a check for "null" into your code.  I think I may raise an issue with boto3.

Comment: Just verified that the initial streaming body has the raw data b'null' but after reading it the raw data in the streaming body is just b''.  So that explains why the first succeeds but the second doesn't.  I'll raise an issue to see if I can figure out if this is expected.

Comment: Verified https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody it's working as intended.  Once you read from the StreamingBody object it's empty.

Comment: I can confirm, it was a missing return statement in the lambda. Thanks for the hint!